# Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Software caused connection abort. flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sockets

I'm currently working on IOT project which is written in flutter. When I create a socket connection with IOT device and send and receive information but suddenly SocketException hhapens. The error description is :

"SocketException: Software caused connection abort (OS Error: Software caused connection abort, errno = 103)"

Also there is no stackTrace. After exception is thrown, I cannot make any http or socket call. What should I do?

```
Future<void> connect(
      {Function()? listener,
      Function(String)? onError,
      int attempt = 0}) async {

    try {
      _socket = await Socket.connect(Urls.socketBase, Urls.socketBasePort);

      listener?.call();

    } on Exception catch(e){
    }
  }


void addListeners(
      {required void Function(String) onData,
      void Function()? onDone,
      void Function(String)? onError}) {

    _socket?.listen(
        (data) {

          if(data.length < 5){
            disconnect();
            onDone?.call();
          } else {
            disconnect();
            onDone?.call();
            onData.call(String.fromCharCodes(data).trim());
          }
        },
        onDone: onDone,
        onError: (error, stack) {

          onError?.call(error.toString());
        },
        cancelOnError: false);

  }
```